# MeteorJS: Put date in dynamic template

Tags: meteor

**WHAT I WANT TO BUILD IN DOM:**

```
   <table>
      <tr> Today </tr>
      <tr> 
         //data from Mongo
      </tr>
      ...
      <tr> Yesterday </tr>
      ....
      //data from Mongo
      ..etc
    </table>
```

**CODE I HAVE :**

```
  <table>
        {{#each posts}}
           {{> postJobs}}
        {{/each}}
    </table>  

    <template name="postJobs">
      <tr>
        ... // data from Mongo
      </tr>
    </template>
```

I think that it is necessary to compare the date from Mongo documents and today date or something like this.

Any idea how to build this ?

Comment: do you have the timestamp in posts? if so this would be an easy problem (I'll explain in an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are requesting how to get the documents from collections grouped by date.

So on Top to see today chat, next block Yesterday, next block Previous Chats

Just call 3 times the same template

```
<template name="main">
  <h1>Today</h1>
  {{> list_posts posts=today}}

  <h1>Yesterday</h1>
  {{> list_posts posts=yesterday}}

  <h1>Previous</h1>
  {{> list_posts posts=previous}}
</template>

<template name="list_posts">
  <table>
    {{#each posts}}
      <tr>
         <td>{{col1}}</td>
         <td>{{colX}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
</template>
```

And then you need this helpers

```
Template.main.helpers({
  today: function() {
    return Posts.find() // col.date >= today
  },
  yesterday: function() {
    return Posts.find() // col.date < today and >= yesterday
  },
  previous: function() {
    return Posts.find() // col.date < yesterday
  }
});
```

Good luck
Tom

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you exactly want to achieve. Comparing to today date would look like this, in an helper (that you can use in an `{{#if compareDate}}` statement:

```
compareDate: function(){
    var today= new Date(new Date().getTime());
    return this.date < today// it will get you true is the date field of your mongo document is older than today
}
```

Extra info, if you need yesterday:

```
var yesterday = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Comment: great, BUT if i want to show posts from today (new Date(new Date().getTime()) > today > a time when the day began ) this must be in helpers not  var today= new Date(new Date().getTime());
    return this.date < today

Comment: today meant "now" in my example. I you want to know if something happened in the current calendar day, you should use moment.js (and if you need to do it accurately, moment timezone too)